# Is there a way in TDD to pass the correct parameter to Mockito.verify without adding one more test with a different parameter?

Tags: java, mockito, tdd

I'm trying to implement a service which calls an object collaborator in TDD, verifying the interaction. The actual code is more complex than this but the example should do.

I used Java and Mockito but the question is not about technology.

I got the following code after the first TDD iteration:

```java
// ServiceTest.java
public class ServiceTest {
    private final SomeObject someObject = Mockito.mock(SomeObject.class);
    private final Service service = new Service(someObject);

    @Test
    void handle_verify_call_to_SomeObject() {
        Body body = new Body();
        body.setSomeString("some parameter");

        service.handle(body);

        verify(someObject).call("some parameter");
    }
}

// Body.java
public class Body {
    private String someString;

    // getter and setter omitted
}

// Service.java
public class Service {
    private final SomeObject someObject;

    public void handle(Body body) {
        someObject.call("some parameter");
    }
}
```

Is there a way (given a a strict TDD perspective) to pass the correct parameter to `someObject.call(...)` without adding one more test or parameterize the test with a different `someString` parameter?

Is it fine to consider implementing the actual code in this case a refactor step? In fact, the test is green before and after the implementation.

I'm finding myself in this situation a lot lately so I decided to ask to the SO community.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Im trying to understand what you want to achieve. Should someObject.call() always be called with the string literal `"some parameter"` ? Than I would hard code that in your test. 
If it should actually be a parameter you should pass it in the method `Service.handle(String parameterHere)` . 
It doesnt really matter, you should test that the call is made with the argument you expect. Could be always the same string or a different string each time, depending on that you should change your test.

Comment: The actual implementation should use `body.getSomeString()`, but the red step of TDD says: "write the least amount of code possible to make your test pass", so I hardcoded the string itself. Then the question comes to my mind: how do I use the correct parameter? Should I add a new test with a different string or what else?